# Firebase not generating Web API Key after entering Authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, access-token

I saw a response to a similar question about someone's Firebase Web API key not automatically generating upon project creation. It seemed as if a consensus solution had been reached, but I am still having issues.

I tried the supposed solution (going into Authentication first), but this did not fix the issue. When I returned to check the status of the Web API key, it was still absent.

Is there a way to manually generate said Web API Key instead?

Answer (score 1):

I had an authentication provider (email/password) already created when I posted this question. This should have automatically generated my Web API Key, so there must have been a bug.

I deleted the provider, and once I did, the key was generated. Now, I am just going to recreate the provider.